# Chrome debugger only stopping at first line

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

The debugger only stops on the first line (if I put a breakpoint there), but does NOT stop if I put a breakpoint at any other line. Even when I type 'debugger' in the script, it is indeed pausing and showing me that it paused in the correct javascript file, but it's showing the first line as the active line of execution.

```
var someVar = 0; //<-- does stop here when I put a break point here

$(document).ready(function()
{
    debugger; //<-- makes it stop but shows the first line as the active line
    alert('here!'); //<-- does not stop with a breakpoint here, but does execute the code
});
```

I tried restarting chrome, and also tried it in Canary, which to my suprise showed the exact same behaviour. Also this behaviour is only happening with 1 specific file. Even If I empty it and put in some simple test code, it remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I removed the file and created it again, and now debugging works as normal again